# Why is ballot and proposal operations are only available in contract API and not in wallet API

Tags: taquito

can you tell my why « ballot » and « proposal » operations are only available in contract API and not in wallet API ?

I want to use them in an app that uses both Ledger and Beacon wallet connection. For Ledger, I can add the Ledger Signer as Tezos signer, and call the contract API. But with Beacon wallet, I don’t know how to do that, except by sending to the wallet a forged transaction to sign.

Comment: I created a [ticket](https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/issues/2526) for this in the repository